# How to write automation test for APIs wrapped with Hystrix

Tags: automated-tests, hystrix

Anyone knows libs or framework that I can use to write automation test for APIs wrapped with Hystrix. I'm thinking using Wiremock but still figuring out how to use it. Thanks